# Is it possible to add a new "not null" column into a table in mssql which has a system versioned history table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table a_s and it has a system versioned history table a_h.
Requirement is to add a new column X1 varchar(5) not null to both a_s & a_h.

Is it possible to create it like this IN MS SQL Server Studio 18?

Comment: No, it's not possible in *SQL Server Management Studio* as it removes the *Design* table option for system-versioned tables, you'll need to add columns using t-sql.

Comment: Honestly, if your intent is/was to use the designer, just don't; it's quirky, lacks features, and can sometimes appear to make (wrong) assumptions about your intent. Learning to use T-SQL for managing your objects is a *far* better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a column to a system versioned table is no different to adding one to a non-system versioned table. When you add a column to the "main" table, the data engine will "automagically" add that column to the history table. If you also define that column with a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` and define the column as `NOT NULL` or state the column needs to be added `WITH VALUES` then rows in the history table will also be populated with that value:

See the following working example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (YourID int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_YourID PRIMARY KEY,
                            SomeColumn varchar(10),
                            ValidFrom datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
                            ValidTo datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
                            PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(ValidFrom, ValidTo))
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.SomeTableHistory));
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn)
VALUES('abc');
GO

UPDATE dbo.SomeTable
SET SomeColumn = 'def'
WHERE YourID = 1
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD AnotherColumn decimal(10,2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_AnotherColumn DEFAULT 0;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD SomeDate date NULL CONSTRAINT DF_SomeDate DEFAULT '20220101' WITH VALUES;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTableHistory;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTableHistory;
```

This gives the following results for `dbo.SomeTable` and `dbo.SomeTableHistory` respectively:

```
YourID      SomeColumn ValidFrom                   ValidTo                     AnotherColumn SomeDate
----------- ---------- --------------------------- --------------------------- ------------- ----------
1           def        2022-07-14 11:09:31.7890645 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 0.00          2022-01-01

YourID      SomeColumn ValidFrom                   ValidTo                     AnotherColumn SomeDate
----------- ---------- --------------------------- --------------------------- ------------- ----------
1           abc        2022-07-14 11:09:31.7890645 2022-07-14 11:09:31.7890645 0.00          2022-01-01
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ad32ff27195bdb1ccb8c3bb6b1646e6)

Answer (score 0):

**This solution worked**:
Add a constraint with default value while adding the not null column and once created, drop the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE A_S  SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);

ALTER TABLE A_H ADD X1 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT cons1 DEFAULT ' ';
ALTER TABLE A_H ADD X2 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT cons2 DEFAULT ' ';
ALTER TABLE A_H ADD X3 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT cons3 DEFAULT ' ';
ALTER TABLE A_S ADD X1 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT cons4 DEFAULT ' ';
ALTER TABLE A_S ADD X2 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT cons5 DEFAULT ' ';
ALTER TABLE A_S ADD X3 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT cons6 DEFAULT ' ';

ALTER TABLE [SUSTAINABILITY_DB_SE].[dbo].[A_S] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[A_H]));

ALTER TABLE A_H DROP CONSTRAINT CONS1;
ALTER TABLE A_H DROP CONSTRAINT CONS2;
ALTER TABLE A_H DROP CONSTRAINT CONS3;
ALTER TABLE A_S DROP CONSTRAINT CONS4;
ALTER TABLE A_S DROP CONSTRAINT CONS5;
ALTER TABLE A_S DROP CONSTRAINT CONS6;
```